# Post.order error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to sort questions by upvotes. The view code looks like this:

```
<%= Question.order(:question.upvotes.size).each do |question| %>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `upvotes' for :question:Symbol
```

Here is my questions controller code:

```
 def upvote
 @question = Question.find params[:id]
 @question.liked_by current_user
 redirect_to comment_questions_path
 end

 def index
 @comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
 @questions = @comment.questions
 end
```

Putting just

```
<% question.upvotes.size %>
```

returns the number of upvotes so that is not the problem.

Comment: You need to use the cached columns as I showed in my previous answer. Try `Question.order(:cached_votes_up).each do |q| ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (again).I wasn't able to add :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0 to questions through a migration. Any idea how i would do this?

Comment: I need to see your app. Can you post it to github?

Comment: Yep [here it is](https://github.com/sideofwhite/omrails)

Comment: Did you run that migration I posted last time? Your repo is a bit out of date. https://github.com/sideofwhite/omrails/blob/master/db/schema.rb

Comment: BTW, the original migration was for `posts`. You'll have to rewrite it to use `questions.

Comment: Do i run "add_column :questions, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0" ?

Comment: That's it! Also make sure to run `Question.find_each(&:update_cached_votes)` to update what's already in your database.

Comment: Haha alright thanks for the patience. I ran 'rails generate migration add_column :questions, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0' but that didn't seem to work. Am i just adding this line to the questions migration i already have?

Comment: You'll want to create a whole new migration, as featured here: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/#caching Except your replacing the word `posts` with `questions`.

Comment: After you create that migration, then you can run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ok awesome that worked! (sorta) Except now it is displaying all the questions ever created instead of just the questions belonging to the comment. Also how would i get most upvoted questions at the top instead of bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the questions attached to the comment, sorted by most votes up at the top of the list.

```
<% @comment.questions.order("cached_votes_up desc").each do |question| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: This worked but now its doing something weird. It's repeating all the posts for each post.eg if i have 3 posts A,B and C it will show ABC 3 times

Comment: Push your latest to github, and include a link to it in a new question.

Comment: [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127905/repeating-posts-in-index-view)