# Repeating posts in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to sort my questions by number of upvotes using the acts_as_votable gem. Everything sorts fine except it displays the whole set of questions n times where n is the # of questions. eg. I post 3 questions A,B and C, it will display ABC ABC ABC.

Here is my view code:

```
<% @comment.questions.order("cached_votes_up desc").each do |question| %>
```

And here is my controller code:

```
def upvote
@question = Question.find params[:id]
@question.liked_by current_user
redirect_to comment_questions_path
end

def index
@comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
@questions = @comment.questions
end
```

[Github](https://github.com/sideofwhite/omrails)

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `_question.html.erb` partial.

When you do `<%= render @questions %>` in `index.html.erb`, that render call will take care of looping over the `@questions` collection and it will render the partial `_question.html.erb` for each `question`. The problem is that in your partial you iterate over all the questions again with `<% @comment.questions.order("cached_votes_total desc").each do |question| %>`.

To solve this, you just need to remove the loop in the first line of `_question.html.erb`, because `<%= render @questions %>` is the same as:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= render 'question', question: question %>
<% end %>
```

Rails docs about rendering collections: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.html.erb` you are doing `render @questions`. This renders the collection `@questions` so it renders for each item in that collection.

It is rendering the view in `_question.html.erb`. In that file, you have your `<% @comment.questions.order("cached_votes_up desc").each do |question| %>`. So that is rendering each question for `@comment`.

You really want to either render the comment in a comment view, and show the questions for that comment, or render the set of questions independent of the comment. Doing both together gives you the multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand much by reading your question but this could help

```
<% @comment.questions.select("DISTINCT(questions.id), *").order("cached_votes_up desc").each do |question| %>
```